# ASP.NET mvc4 GridView doesnot show data from DataBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem, into my project i'm trying to get data from my database into GridView, but on the page data not shown... but in VisualStudio designer mode, i can retreive data into gridview...
what i'm doing wrong?

here it code in .aspx page

```
<div id="default">
<%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <fieldset>
        <ol class="actionRefresh">
            <a href="/Admin/UsersInRolesList" target="_self" title="Refresh Users In Roles List">Users In Roles List<b>&nbsp;</b> </a>
        </ol>

        <form runat="server" id="frmUsers">

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsUsers" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
                SelectCommand="UserProfiles_s_sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DataSourceMode="DataReader" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserProfileID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PageSize" Type="Int32" />a
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PageNum" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Sort" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Additional" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        No data found.
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>

        </form>

        <div id="divBackTo">
            <a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Admin") %>" target="_self" title="Back to Menu"><<
                &nbsp;&nbsp; Back to Menu </a>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

in controller i have this code:

```
try
        { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, ex.Message);
        }return View();
```

and when i loaded my page i have "No data found" displayed in gridview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView is for ASP.NET WebForms, not ASP.NET MVC. In MVC, the Controller retrieves data as Models and sends them to the View. There is no data access in the View.

See [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) for a number of tutorials, including data access.